# Linking tables for a report

Tags: soql

I'd like to create a report that links two tables together. One is the Case table with some custom fields, Topic__c and Sub_Topic_*c. I'd like to create another table that has the same two fields so that based on the Topic*_c + Sub_Topic__c values in a Case record, I can return values from the second table. I know how to do this easily in SQL Server or Oracle. How would I do this in SalesForce SOQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you wouldn't do this with SOQL. Instead, you'd do this with Reports using a Joined Report. Go to Reports and create a new report and select Cases as the object. Once inside report builder, use the menu (click on Tabular Format) to tell it you want the type of report to be a Joined Report. Create a new block by dragging Cases into the preview pane again to the right of the existing table block. Just drag the fields you want into each of the two tables you see in the window, you'll also have separate filtering criteria you can set for each one. You should be able to filter the tables based on a variety of criteria, including custom cross-filters.

For more details on how to create these reports, I recommend you download the [Analytics Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_analytics/workbook_analytics.pdf). There's an example of creating a joined report in Tutorial 4 that should walk you through what I've roughly described in much better detail.

Comment: The problem with this is that the custom object does not show up in the list of available links. I was hoping I could do this without adding a reference from the case to the custom object and just do a simple join like you can in SQL.

Comment: In trying to do this, it looks like I can't create a dynamic association between fields that should have the same value. So I have Case.Topic__c and Case.Sub_Topic__c then in a custom object, CaseQuestion__c I have CaseQuestion__c.Topic__c and CaseQuestion__c.Sub_Tobpic__c I'd like to just make a simple join between the two tables on these fields. The report designer does not allow me to select these fields for linking.

Comment: Not being familiar with your object fields, it's difficult for me to advise, but if Topic__c and Sub_Topic__c are related as I think, you may need to "bucket" the sub topic fields in each of the reports in order to group them related to a Topic__c, then link them in the way you want to. Look earlier in the PDF I referred you to and at Chapter 10 of this PDF: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf for more on the topic.

Comment: The way I resolved this is to just add a reference field to the CaseQuestion__c object, then added formula fields that then gather data from the referenced instance. This works but forces you to add to the custom fields and we have some objects that are very close to the max.(One of the down sides of allowing users to have everything they want in order to get them to adopt new technology)